# Protractor - run multiple tests in parallel on different browsers

Tags: angularjs, selenium-grid, protractor

I can't find any information on how to set this up, but it seems like a pretty basic concept, so I'm sure there's an answer out there.

I know how to run protractor on different browsers by setting the `browserName` property of the `capabilities` object in the config.  And that's working great.  I can set it to `'chrome'` or `'firefox'` or whatever I need and it runs just as expected.  But the only way to run a single test suite against multiple browsers (as far as I know) is to create separate config files, each with a different `browserName` and then run each browser with its own config.  This works, but its really slow because tests are then running in sequence, rather than concurrently.

Is there any way to run it on multiple browsers in parallel?

Can it be done on SauceLabs? or even using a local Selenium-Grid?

We are just trying to streamline our testing process and this would be a huge help.  Any suggestions or info would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do u mean run parallel test

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update Feb 2014 - This answer is no longer valid. Use Paolo Moretti's answer below.**

---

There may be a better way to do this but currently I am just executing these as concurrent Grunt tasks.

1) Add the grunt concurrent plugin

```
npm install grunt-concurrent --save-dev
```

2) Add a task for each browser under grunt.initConfig. We can add the browser as an arg to re-use our configuration file.

```
protractor: {
        options: {
            keepAlive: true,
            singleRun: false,
            configFile: "test/protractor.conf.js"
        },
        run_chrome: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: "chrome"
                }
            }
        },
        run_firefox: {
            options: {
                args: {
                    browser: "firefox"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

3) Register these as tasks;

```
grunt.registerTask('protractor-chrome', ['protractor:run_chrome']);
grunt.registerTask('protractor-firefox', ['protractor:run_firefox']);
```

4) Create your concurrent task under grunt.initConfig

```
concurrent: {
        protractor_test: ['protractor-chrome', 'protractor-firefox']
    },
```

5) Add the grunt task for concurrent

```
grunt.registerTask('protractor-e2e', ['concurrent:protractor_test']);
```

And executing that should give you concurrent protractor tests.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer until Protractor adds direct support for Selenium Grid.  See issue #111 [How to pass more configuration to selenium grid?](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/111) and [Running Selenium tests in parallel](http://sauceio.com/index.php/tag/parallel-testing/).

Answer (score 65):

There's new option called `multiCapabilities` for that:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}, {
  'browserName': 'firefox'
}],
```

Here's a [complete example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/multiConf.js).

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Do you know of any way to run separate spec files in each of those browsers? It looks like you can only run a single test suite in multiple browsers, but I'd really like to be able to run multiple specs in parallel...

Comment: If you are using grunt-protractor-runner you can pass specs as a parameter. In that way you could create a task for each spec and then run all these in parallel using grunt-concurrent or something similar.

Comment: I added above code and its not opening Firefox with or without FF driver. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 14):

using `multiCapabilities` will run all the tests in each of the browsers. So the configuration below will run every test twice, once in Firefox and once in Chrome:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}, {
  'browserName': 'firefox'
}],
```

If you would rather have each test file just run once, but split up among multiple browsers, then use the `splitTestsBetweenCapabilities` option:

```
splitTestsBetweenCapabilities: true
```

[This blog post](http://blog.yodersolutions.com/run-protractor-tests-in-parallel/) goes into further detail about the `splitTestsBetweenCapabilities`

Comment: That sounds great. What exactly does the `splitTestsBetweenCapabilities` option do?

Comment: This option is removed right now; refer https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L77

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I've found that they are adding the feature for parallel execution as we speak! :D

Take a look at this: https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/492

That change was merged to master, but a newer one (512) is still open. As soon as they merge it to master (should be today or tomorrow according to the discussion in the pull request) it should be in your hands :D.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That'll be great once that's merged in.

Answer (score 1):

BrowserStack also can be used for this purposes. It has quite detailed start guide: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node, but it is not free

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieve this. Simply add the section below to the conf.js file:

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  shardTestFiles: true,
  maxInstances: 1
}
```

`shardTestFiles = true` causes each spec file to run in a new browser instance. `maxInstances` is the max number of browsers that can be open at the same time.

Comment: Did you have any problems with intermittent failures when doing this?

Comment: I ran into a few issues that needed to be fixed in the code. I don't remember any specifics right now.