# Protractor Framework setup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

While setting up protractor, encountered following error while trying to start webdriver manager :

```
C:\ang\Angular_modules\node_modules>webdriver-manager start
[05:55:09] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\\usatlkilne01-ctxcifs\ctxprofiles\FolderRedirW10\ajoshi056\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.35.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=\\usatlkilne01-ctxcifs\ctxprofiles\FolderRedirW10\ajoshi056\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.19.1.exe -jar \\usatlkilne01-ctxcifs\ctxprofiles\FolderRedirW10\ajoshi056\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -port 4444
[05:55:09] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 15016
Error: Could not find or load main class org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3
[05:55:13] I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1
```

Java version 9.0.4 installed on my machine

Please let me know how to do it in detail

Answer (score 0):

The error does gives us some hint as follows :

```
[05:55:09] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\\usatlkilne01-ctxcifs\ctxprofiles\FolderRedirW10\ajoshi056\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.35.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=\\usatlkilne01-ctxcifs\ctxprofiles\FolderRedirW10\ajoshi056\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.19.1.exe -jar \\usatlkilne01-ctxcifs\ctxprofiles\FolderRedirW10\ajoshi056\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -port 4444
```

From the error trace logs it seems :

- Protractor is considering **`chromedriver_2.35`** as the **ChromeDriver** binary (e.g. `chromedriver_2.35.exe`)
- Protractor is considering **`geckodriver-v0.19.1`** as the **GeckoDriver** binary (e.g. `geckodriver-v0.19.1.exe`)

Seems, either the absolute location of the *WebDriver* binaries are incorrect or you have to change the name of the binaries to the *default* names as **chromedriver.exe** and **geckodriver.exe**

Comment: Hi Debanjan, Thanks for the help. Can you tell me how to change the names of the binaries or to change the location of webdriver. I am completely new to this

Comment: @Ash Just cross check on this path, whether these binaries exists or not.                                                                                         
 \\usatlkilne01ctxcifs\ctxprofiles\FolderRedirW10\ajoshi056\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.35.exe -

Answer (score 0):

@Ash it seems like the problem is not with your webdriver. And you don't want rename the webdriver. I hope you have set something like the below in your Protractor conf.js.

`multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'firefox'
}, {
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}]`

if you change it to `capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'firefox'
   }
}`

or `capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}`

And if you really want to run on multiple browsers. [Please refer this page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692008/protractor-run-multiple-tests-in-parallel-on-different-browsers)

If this solves kindly try to upvote and check this as correct answer.

If not can you say more about your problem.

One more thing did your ran the

```
webdriver-manager update
```

before doing webdriver-manager start?

Answer (score 0):

seems your `selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar` is not **integral** in folder:

`\\usatlkilne01-ctxcifs\ctxprofiles\FolderRedirW10\ajoshi056\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\`,

please try to unzip it and try to find there is a class `org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3` ?

Delete the current `selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar`, get a new one.