# How to use Protractor for Chrome, FF, IE?

Tags: protractor

How do I  Run Chrome, FF, IE browsers for test execution?
I have been using directConnect: true for Chrome and FF; and I'm aware that if this is set when I try and run IE, then it will throw and error. From what I understand, I need to have directConnect: true in order to use Chrome and FF.

I've been trying to figure the conf.js file with multiCapabilities for all 3 browsers, but cant seen to figure how to get all 3 of then to run the test.

multiCapabilities : [
        {
            'browserName' : 'chrome'
        }, {
            'browserName': 'internet explorer',

```
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'version': '11',


    },
    {   'browserName': 'firefox'

    }
],
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor - run multiple tests in parallel on different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692008/protractor-run-multiple-tests-in-parallel-on-different-browsers)

Comment: `I need to have directConnect: true in order to use Chrome and FF.`  That is not true.  It is one option sure, but you can also have a selenium server running and connect to that instead

Comment: http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/ - You can skip the VM setup (first 3 steps) if you are running on your own machine

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate conf.js files for different browsers. 
Also I have separate folder for reporting and run them one after another. 
This is one approach. Other is to run them in parallel using selenium server.